# how to define a 2d discrete delta function that can take array input in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, 2d, delta

```
function y = dd2(x1,x2)
y=0;
if x1==0 && x2==0
  y=1;
end
```

This would not work because the input cannot be an array.
I hope to make it can work for an array X of 1*m, and an array Y of 1*n
so when you dd2(X,Y) it creates a m*n matrix with 1 at the position where X=0, Y=0 and zero otherwise

Is there any function that does this has already been implemented in matlab? (like a 2D discrete delta function) I didn't find it.. The dirac(x) would return inf which I want is zero. Is there a way to change the inf to 1? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a magical function called [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) that does almost everything in MATLAB and certainly finds another perfect setup here. The implementation with it would look something like this -

```
y = bsxfun(@and,x1(:)==0,x2(:).'==0)
```

Sample run with `x1` as `1x4` and `x2` as `1x6` -

```
x1 =
     0    -1    -1     0
x2 =
    -1    -1    -1    -1     0     0
y =
     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1
```

Look at the positions of `0`'s in `x1`, `x2` and `1`'s in the output `y` to verify the results.

---

**General Case Solution**

For a general case, you can define an [anonymous function](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) like so -

```
func1 = @(x1,x2) x1==0 & x2==0
```

Then, use it within `bsxfun` for the deseired output -

```
y = bsxfun(func1,x1(:),x2(:).')
```

Thus, with every new conditional statement, you only need to change `func1`! As an example, you can add one more conditional statement in it -

```
func1 = @(x1,x2) x1==0 & x2==0 | x1 <0
```

Comment: That really helps! It's probably better to change `x1(:)==0,x2(:).'==0`  to `x1(:).'==0,x2(:)==0` by x and y order convention. A follow-up question: if I have multiple functions in the same folder, how can I specify @and is referring to my dd2() function?